# Появляется блок при нажатии на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

Как сделать что бы при нажатии на кнопку появлялся блок в центре экрана.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button class="btn btn-info">Заказать счет</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button class="btn btn-info">Заказать счет</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button class="btn btn-info">Заказать счет</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Имеется три кнопки,у каждой кнопки при нажатии должен появляться блок с разной информацией.
Кому не трудно могли бы поподробнее расписать все?

Answer (score 1):

Вот простейший пример модального окна.

```js
function ShowModal(elId) {
  var modalAll = document.getElementById(elId);
  modalAll.style.display = "flex";
}

function HideModal(ell) {
  if (ell.classList.contains('modal-all')) {
    ell.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
.modal-all {
  display: none;
  background: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.3);
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
  width: 200px;
  height: 120px;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button onclick="ShowModal('m1')" class="btn btn-info">Заказать счет</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button onclick="ShowModal('m2')" class="btn btn-info">Заказать счет</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <button onclick="ShowModal('m3')" class="btn btn-info">Заказать счет</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="m1" class="modal-all" onclick="HideModal(this)">
  <div id="m1i" class="modal">
    Форма 1 форма 1 форма 1
  </div>
</div>
<div id="m2" class="modal-all" onclick="HideModal(this)">
  <div id="m2i" class="modal">
    Форма 2 форма 2 форма 2
  </div>
</div>
<div id="m3" class="modal-all" onclick="HideModal(this)">
  <div id="m3i" class="modal">
    Форма 3 форма 3 форма 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
window.onload = () => {
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-info'),
    modalsData = [
        'MODAL 1',
        'MODAL 2',
        'MODAL 3'
    ],
    openedModalId;

let passDataAndOpenModal = function (data) {
    let parentBlock =document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0],
        block = document.createElement('div');
    block.className = 'info-modal';
    block.innerHTML = data;
    parentBlock.appendChild(block);
}

for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if(document.getElementsByClassName('info-modal').length > 0){
            let modal = document.getElementsByClassName('info-modal')[0];
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].removeChild(modal);
        }
        passDataAndOpenModal(modalsData[i]);
        openedModalId = i;
    }, false);
}
};
```

```css
.info-modal{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid grey; 
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button class="btn btn-info">Заказать счет</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button class="btn btn-info">Заказать счет</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <button class="btn btn-info">Заказать счет</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```